# Hiding python comments with Listings

Tags: listings, python, comments, hide

I want to include Python code to be formatted with listings but I just want the code neat and compact. No comments shall be printed at all, as well as no empty lines.

The *easy* way would be to strip the code of comments, but that's bypassing the problem and not finding a solution. I want a solution. A solution would mean I do NOT have to edit the source file being imported.

I have tried the following:

#### Approach 1

```latex
\lstdefinestyle{py_without_comments}{%
    language     = python,
    morecomment  = [l][\nullfont]{\#},
    emptylines   = *1,
}
```

Which doesn't print the comments, but the lines stay there since the text reach the output, just LaTeX prints it with `nullfont`.

#### Approach 2

```latex
\lstdefinestyle{py_without_comments}{%
    language     = python,
    morecomment  = [is]{\#}{\^^M},
    emptylines   = *1,
}
```

Approach 2 ignores all comment lines from the `#` to the end of the line.
Problem is, the end of the line also disappears!
Say you have this code:

```python
def foo():
    if cond1: bar() #Some explanation
    if cond2: baz() #Some other explanation
    if cond3: bye() #Even more explanations
```

It would print like this:

```python
def foo():
    if cond1: bar()        if cond2: baz()        if cond3: bye()
```

Which is undesirable, unpythonic, and ugly.

#### Approach 3

```latex
\lstdefinestyle{py_without_comments}{%
    language     = python,
    morecomment  = [il]{\#},
    emptylines   = *1,
}
```

This one should work like a charm, but for some reason it wipes out all the code from the first comment on (see `foo()` example).

Thus I am looking for something else to try. Could it be that this is not possible with listings?

Cheers and thanks in advance.

---

### Edit 1:

MWE can be found [here](https://github.com/kyordhel/mwe/tree/master/listings-py)

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: Done.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something that works. It plays with some of `listings`' internals.
I'm not sure if there's a better solution. Consuming the end-of-line delimiter (your approach 2, above) and adding it back if the line is not empty does not seem to work.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

% Default settings.
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=5pt,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  rulecolor=\color{black},
}

% The \incomment macro and auxiliary stuff.
\newif\ifnocomment
\newif\ifemptyline
\makeatletter
% When a line starts, it's empty and we're not in a comment.
\lst@AddToHook{InitVarsBOL}{\global\emptylinetrue\global\nocommenttrue}
% When something is printed, the line is not empty.
\lst@AddToHook{PostOutput}{\global\emptylinefalse}
% When we're in a comment...
\def\incomment#1{%
  % if we just entered...
  \ifnocomment%
    \global\nocommentfalse%
    % and the line is empty, then remove this line.
    \ifemptyline\global\advance\lst@newlines\m@ne\fi%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\lstdefinestyle{python_without_comments}{%
  language=python,
  morecomment=[l][\incomment]{\#},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=python_without_comments]
def f(x): return x + 1 #

# This is function foo...
def foo():
  if cond1: bar()  # Some explanation
  if cond2: baz()  # Some other explanation
  if cond3: bye()  # Even more explanations

# And this is function bar
def bar():  # let's see
  # some more comment
  return 42 # here?
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image: Result]

It may print an empty line at the end of the text, if there are comments there; I'm not sure how to remove this.

---

Edit: My original answer used hook `OutputBox` instead of `PostOutput`. This did not work well with tabs.

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer! Indeed it works but `\incomment` does the same as `\nullfont`. If you have comment lines (comment only) `\incomment` does not print the text but you get a blank line. If your comment line is 3-lines tall then you get 3 blank lines.

Comment: @Kyordhel, this is not what I see with the example in my answer (LaTeX source and result). Could you provide a Python script that is wrongly formatted?

Comment: First and foremost, thanks for your time and help, @nickie. I updated the [MWE](https://github.com/kyordhel/mwe/tree/master/listings-py) (output [here](https://github.com/kyordhel/mwe/blob/master/listings-py/nickie.sol.pdf)). When the code is all compact your code works, but if you have some blank lines above comments everything goes broken. In python this becomes nonsensical since indentation matters.

Comment: @Kyordhel, it seems that my solutions does not work well with tab characters. I never use tabs in code, especially for Python, because it's problematic anyway.

Comment: @Kyordhel, check my revised answer. I only changed hook `OutputBox` to `PostOutput`. This seems to have fixed the issue with the tabs.